# Why NOT MATCHED Condition In MERGE SQL Not Working

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

i have a simple table and want to update or insert data based on some conditions.
So, I'm using MERGE syntax for this case.
But when it's turn to "not matched" condition, this logic not working as expected.

Here's the syntax :

```
MERGE INTO ABC_TABLE mi 
USING (SELECT DISTINCT IDFROM ABC_TABLE  WHERE TRUNC(INF_DAT_TIME)='27-APR-23' AND ID = 'ABC')DT ON ( mi.ID = dt.ID) 
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET mi.REGION='JAKARTA', mi.DAT_TIME='20-FEB-23 11.50.18.000000000 AM', mi.AB_DAT_TIME=null, mi.COUNT_1=366, mi.COUNT_2=366, mi.COUNT_3=1042, mi.COUNT_4=1041, 
        mi.OPEN_AMT=2815, mi.CLOSING_AMT=116, mi.DEL=99, mi.RTR=99, mi.RJC=99, mi.LAST_UPDATE_TIME=sysdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN insert (ABC_ID, ID, REGION, DAT_TIME, AB_DAT_TIME, COUNT_1, COUNT_2, COUNT_3, COUNT_4, OPEN_AMT, CLOSING_AMT, DEL, RTR, RJC, CREATED_TIME, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATE_BY) 
        values (SYS_GUID(),'TEST','','','','','','','','','','','','',sysdate,'SYSTEM',sysdate,'SYSTEM');
```

When this query executed and there's nothing to merged , it's should be execute the insert query but in this case the insert query not executed.

And the sql log only show this when not matched :
0 rows merged.

Expectation :
When matched update (existing -> this is working fine)
When not matched insert (existing -> not working)

Is there anyone can give me a clue for this case ?

Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: check if the SELECT statement in the USING clause is returning any rows with the ID value of 'ABC'. Also: don't use language in dates, use ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DD format for date literals e.g. `TRUNC(INF_DAT_TIME) = DATE  '2023-04-27'`